# Detect if the computer was sleeping at a certain hour

Tags: windows-7, sleep

Is there a way to detect if a computer running Windows 7 was in sleep mode at a certain hour?

Comment: Look at the event logs

Comment: @DavidPostill state what event logs

Comment: @barlop Added close duplicate which explains all.